# Attempting to install termios gem results in make errors

Tags: ruby, rubygems, installation, termios

I'm attempting to install the termios gem on OS X 10.7 with ruby 1.9.3-p194. It used to install fine, but now, even when i try to install it in 1.9.3-p125, i get the same errors:

https://gist.github.com/83a4ff80fa882dcd6937

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gem install ruby-termios`
http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-termios

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This problem has been bothering me for a few days now, and #ruby, reddit, and lots of googling couldn't help.